# Column sorting by label

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with 20 columns. The first column header is gene, then the next 19 are for different experiments.

```
gene    1-1164-KO-aa8   22-1264-wt-aa8   15-1175-wt-aa9  27-1195-KO-aa9   ...
abc      11.9898           11.9898         11.9898         11.9898        ...
cde      11.9898           11.9898         11.9898         11.9898        ... 
 .
 .
```

I need to order the columns based on their labels.

Keep the first column GENE in place and sort the rest based on only this part of the labels (wt-aa8, wt-aa9, KO-aa8, KO-aa9).

First GENE then all wt-aa8, followed by all wt-aa9, then all KO-aa8 and lastly all KO-aa9. But the sorted columns need to have the original full names (like 1-1164-KO-aa8) after ordering them.

So it should look like this:

```
gene    22-1264-wt-aa8  22-1264-wt-aa8  1-1164-KO-aa8   27-1195-KO-aa9
abc      11.9898         11.9898         11.9898          11.9898
cde      11.9898         11.9898         11.9898          11.9898
```

Normally I only have numbers on the header and do a df.sort which obviously did not work and unfortunately I have to keep the original column names.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Link to an example df.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzv1SNKM1p4uYW9yQWJNT21NNVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your description of how they should be sorted is confusing for a non-gene person.

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried to make it more clear. Is it better?

Comment: I think the main question is what the logic is for sorting the latter part of the labels, i.e. why does `KO` need to come after `wt`?  What's the range of possible strings like `KO` and `wt` that you might need to deal with?  Is it just those two (in which case the solution is trivial), or is it more complicated, and if so where does the ordering come from?

Comment: I need similar columns to be next to each other. All the columns with WT(aa8 and aa9) in the headers are going to be later compared to all columns with KO(aa8 and aa9). And then only WT aa-8 will be compared to KO-aa8. There are many variations that can be done here (WT-aa8 compared to WT-aa9, etc). But if I have them all ordered I can use the index to do it.

Comment: First, the columns don't need to be next to each other to do comparisons.  But second, the logic behind the ordering still isn't clear.  The example you have repeats the `wt-aa8` column, but even if it was `wt-aa9` (as I imagine it should be), it's still not clear where to place a column with `AdKi` instead of `wt` or `KO`.

Comment: To put it another way: do you just care about having all the `wt` columns together (and ordered from `aa8` to `aa9`), and the same for `KO`, or is there something special about `wt` that means it should go before `KO` even though it comes later in the alphabet?  That's what isn't clear, and needs to be before we can give useful advice.

Comment: Ohhh now I got it. The columns need to be next to each other because of a database convention. WT and KO mean wild type and knock out this columns are named after conditions not in alphabetical order. And in this database the wild type always have to come first. 22-1264-wt-aa8, would mean something like, patient 22 - protocol1124- wildtype- male aa8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111805/discussion-between-asgm-and-carol-m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the columns with similar strings just need to be next to each other, then you can do it fairly simply.

```
coldict = {c: c.split('-', 2)[2] for c in df.columns[1:]}
df = df[['gene'] + sorted(df.ix[:, 1:].columns, key=lambda x: coldict[x])]
```

First, you make a dictionary that only includes the "sortable" part of the columns.  We only use the columns after the first, to exclude the `gene` column.  The splitting is based on the file you included, not the one in the example, but you could modify it.

Second, you make a dataframe where the column order is determined not by the raw column name, but by the (sorted) value in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a one off for this example, and normally you can just sort by numbers, Try to open it in excel, then you can just drag and drop the columns into the correct order, then save it again.

alternately, rename the headers as 1.1-1164-KO-aa8   3.22-1264-wt-aa8   2.15-1175-wt-aa9  7.27-1195-KO-aa9

then sort by number.

Definite hack, but for 20 columns pretty fast.

Comment: Unfortunally this is a first but you'll be happening a lot and the the next file has 500 columns and 24000 rows. So I thought it was better to figure it out. hehe